# What's the React best practice for getting data that will be used for page render?

Tags: reactjs

I need to get data that will be used for the page that I'm rendering. I'm currently getting the data in a useEffect hook. I don't think all the data has been loaded before the data is being used in the render. It's giving me an error "property lastName of undefined" when I try to use it in the Chip label.

I'm not sure where or how I should be handling the collection of the data since it's going to be used all throughout the page being rendered. Should I collect the data outside the App function?

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [teams] = useState(["3800", "0200", "0325", "0610", "0750", "0810"]);
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    teams.forEach(teamId => {
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = authKey;

      axios.get(endPoints.roster + teamId)
        .then((response) => {
          let teamPlayers = response.data.teamPlayers;

          teamPlayers.forEach(newPlayer => {
            setPlayers(players => [...players, newPlayer]);
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    });
  }, []);


  let numPlayersNode =
    <Chip
      variant="outlined"
      size="small"
      label={players[1].lastName}
    />

  return (...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over a `teamPlayers` array and add them one at a time, updating state each time, but `players` is always the same so you don't actually add them to state other than the last `newPlayer`.

Convert

```
teamPlayers.forEach(newPlayer => {
  setPlayers(players => [...players, newPlayer]);
});
```

to

```
setPlayers(prevPlayers => [...prevPlayers, ...teamPlayers]);
```

Adds all new players to the previous list of players using a [functional state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

You also have an initial state of an empty array (`[]`), so on the first render you won't have any data to access. You can use a truthy check (or guard pattern) to protect against `access ... of undefined...` errors.

```
let numPlayersNode =
  players[1] ? <Chip
    variant="outlined"
    size="small"
    label={players[1].lastName}
  /> : null
```

Comment: That worked perfectly - Thank you. I will look up functional state update to try to understand better. The truthy check makes perfect sense now.

Comment: @sbaden Here is a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-bad-and-good-state-updates-2rtbk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) I've created to help illustrate the difference between regular and functional state updates.

Comment: I see how the truthy check works but say I wanted to wait until all of the data has loaded and I don't know how much data there is. How would I get the code to wait?

Comment: @sbaden Use the array length, i.e. `players.length ? /* render players.map(... */ : /* render null or some useful text, maybe a loading spinner */`. (*Apologies, syntax is hard to read in comments*) Check out [react conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: I tried using this code in a Typography component {players.length ? players[players.length - 1].lastName : null} and it just keeps updating the lastName value

Comment: @sbaden Sounds like a new/different issue, please either update your question here (not preferred) or open a new issue (preferred). Feel free to drop a link to it here and I can take a look when I have a chance.

Answer (score 1):

You should always create a null check or loading before rendering stuff. because initially that key does not exists. For example

```
<Chip
  variant="outlined"
  size="small"
  label={players.length > 0 && players[1].lastName}
/>
```

this is an example of a null check

For loading create a loading state.

Answer (score 1):

When functional component is rendered first, `useEffect` is executed only after function is returned.

and then, if the state is changed inside of `useEffect1`, the component will be rendered again. Here is a example

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

const A = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect');
        setList([{a : 1}, {a : 2}]);
    }, []);

    return (() => {
        console.log('return')
        return (
            <div>
                {list[0]?.a}
            </div>
        )
    })()
}

export default A;
```

if this component is rendered, what happen on the console?

[image]

As you can see, the component is rendered before the state is initialized.

In your case, error is happened because `players[1]` is `undefined` at first render.

the simple way to fix error, just add null check or optional chaining like `players[1]?.lastName`.